# How does Bowyer-Watson algorithm for Delaunay triangulation run in O(n^2) but runs over all the simplexes?

Tags: time-complexity, triangulation, delaunay, simplex

The Bowyer-Watson algorithm for Delaunay triangulation is known to run in O(n^2) according to the authors, where n is the number of data points in R^d.

In addition, the algorithm (for example, as is written in Bowyer's paper, at stage 5 of the algorithm), runs over all the simplexes, (also runs over simplexes that will be later deleted).

How does it settle with the fact that there are O(n^{d/2}) simplexes in Delaunay triangulation?

One should expect from the algorithm to run in Omega(n^{d/2}), (and maybe even in a worse time complexity - since it runs over "extra simplexes").

Thanks!

Comment: There aren't too many algorithm geeks here. You might do better asking on the CS stack exchange.

Comment: what is `d` in your question?

Comment: Anyway you can O(n log n) time complexity if you have some way of finding the triangle a given point is in in O(log n) time. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59582271/1413244

Comment: Thanks for the answer @jwezorek
$d$ is the dimension - meaning that the points are in R^d.
Also, the fact that we can run the algorithm in O(n log n) doesn't solve the question.